# Webpack doesn't inline a const from another file

Tags: javascript, webpack

I have a file with a few time calculations.
In order to "DRY", at its top there's a

```
const HOUR_MS = 60 * 60 * 1000
```

In the transpiled output each `HOUR_MS` occurrence is inlined with `36e5`.

So far, so good ^_^

BUT! If I extract this const to its own file, because I want to reuse it in more places, this no longer works.

Instead, the transpiled output now has references to that const (e.g. `r.HOUR_MS`) which means it's not as minified as it can be.

Is this a deliberate behavior (which maybe I can suppress with some flag) or is it an optimization oversight? (was about to report it, but their GitHub bug template suggested I'd ask here first)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This phenomenon is problematic, but due to the multiplicity of layers (2) working together to generate output, this feat is not feasible.

This is because `import` and `export` behave differently than `CommonJS`. 
No matter what, `import` and `export` are by reference (even with primitive variables), whereas `CommonJS` does not manipulate the exported values (therefore, primitive values won't be referenced).

**Proof that `import` and `export` are by reference:**

1.ts

```
export let number = 10;

export function increase() {
    number++;
}
```

2.ts

```
import {number, increase} from './1';

console.log(number);
increase();
console.log(number);
```

the log will print 10, 11

**Layer 1: `TypeScript` Transpiler**

```
const number = 10;
console.log(number);
```

Will transpile to:

```
const number = 10;
console.log(number);
```

But

```
export const number = 10;
console.log(number);
```

Will transpile to: (**This is where the problem begins**)

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.number = 10;
console.log(exports.number);
```

**Layer 2: `uglify-es`**

```
const number = 10;
console.log(number);
```

Will compress to

```
console.log(10);
```

But

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
exports.number = 10;
console.log(exports.number);
```

Will compress to: (**This is where the problem ends**)

```
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: !0 });
exports.number = 10;
console.log(exports.number);
```

And this is why this optimization will never work without any common standard between the layers.

Comment: With `let` I understand your answer.
However, I'm talking about `const`.

Comment: I believe that the "export" stop that from working is because when you convert the code from typescript it turns to object only if it is exported, and because of that the optimization is not working. I will try to prove it later this week. (The fact that when it's exported coverting it to an object is in your question (`r.HOUR_MS`), but it didn't check if without been exported it's not in an object).

Comment: My question is not related to TypeScript, but this is a great answer nonetheless. Accepted - thanks!
(p.s. not related to the issue at hand, but you made me realize I should consider switching from 'import' to 'require' - where my const will still not be inlined, but the output package is at least a bit smaller)